# Different Anonymous Mobile Client Authentication Methods with Node REST API

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, swift, jwt

I am learning by doing and I am looking to learn some things.

I have the following:

Client (iOS/Swift):

- Should not be required to register (no email/username/password/phone number).
- Connection to server is secure (SSL)
- I want users to remain anonymous and log them in without having them enter any username and password combination. The way I do it is to currently generate a UUID and password combination on the device, save it to keychain and upload it to server (hashing the password first as well). **Not sure where to proceed from there**.

Server API (Node/Express):

- Unprotected endpoints (anyone with the URL can call them)

What I want to do:

1. Loginless authentication of mobile users
2. Protect my endpoints so that only the iOS clients can consume them, for example getting a list of articles (api/v1/articles)
3. In addition to the above protection, protect some endpoints so that only "registered" users can interact with some endpoints (for example: /{article_id}/favorite)

I am looking to maybe (if applicable) make use of JWT (simple-jwt), client side API Key, API Secret, Client Secret, Client UUID, PassportJS, Tokens, OAuth/2 etc...